# C# slowdown while creating a bitmap - calculating distances from a large List of places for each pixel

Tags: c#

I'm creating a graphic of the glow of lights above a geographic location based upon Walkers Law: Skyglow=0.01*Population*DistanceFromCenter^-2.5

I have a CSV file of places with 66,000 records using 5 fields (id,name,population,latitude,longitude), parsed on the FormLoad event and stored it in:

```
List<string[]> placeDataList
```

Then I set up nested loops to fill in a bitmap using SetPixel. For each pixel on the bitmap, which represents a coordinate on a map (latitude and longitude), the program loops through placeDataList – calculating the distance from that coordinate (pixel) to each place record. The distance (along with population) is used in a calculation to find how much cumulative sky glow is contributed to the coordinate from each place record.

So, for every pixel, 66,000 distance calculations must be made. The problem is, this is predictably EXTREMELY slow – on the order of one line of pixels per 30 seconds or so on a 320 pixel wide image. This is unrelated to SetPixel, which I know is also slow, because the speed is similarly slow when adding the distance calculation results to an array.

I don’t actually need to test all 66,000 records for every pixel, only the records within 150 miles (i.e. no skyglow is contributed to a coordinate from a small town 3000 miles away). But to find which records are within 150 miles of my coordinate I would still need to loop through all the records for each pixel. I can't use a smaller number of records because all 66,000 places contribute to skyglow for SOME coordinate in my map as it loops. This seems like a Catch-22, so I know there must be a better method out there. Like I mentioned, the slowdown is related to how many calculations I’m making per pixel, not anything to do with the bitmap. Any suggestions?

```
    private void fillPixels(int width)
    {
        Color pixelColor;
        int pixel_w = width;
        int pixel_h = (int)Math.Floor((width * 0.424088664));
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pixel_w, pixel_h);
        for (int i = 0; i < pixel_h; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < pixel_w; j++)
            {
                pixelColor = getPixelColor(i, j);
                bmp.SetPixel(j, i, pixelColor);

            }

        bmp.Save("Nightfall", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        MessageBox.Show("Done");

    }

    private Color getPixelColor(int height, int width)
    {
        int c;
        double glow,d,cityLat,cityLon,cityPop;
        double testLat, testLon;
        int size_h = (int)Math.Floor((size_w * 0.424088664)); ;
        testLat = (height * (24.443136 / size_h)) + 24.548874;
        testLon = (width * (57.636853 / size_w)) -124.640767;

        glow = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < placeDataList.Count; i++)
        {
            cityPop=Convert.ToDouble(placeDataList[i][2]);
            cityLat=Convert.ToDouble(placeDataList[i][3]);
            cityLon=Convert.ToDouble(placeDataList[i][4]);
            d = distance(testLat, testLon, cityLat, cityLon,"M");
            if(d<150)
                glow = glow+(0.01 * cityPop * Math.Pow(d, -2.5));
        }
        if (glow >= 1) glow=1;
        c = (int)Math.Ceiling(glow * 255);
        return Color.FromArgb(c, c, c);            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, one obvious problem is that you're parsing the string for every city for every pixel.

I would *strongly* suggest that the first thing you do is convert your `placeDataList` into a more sensible format - a `List<City>` where each city has properties of `Latitude`, `Longitude` and `Population`.

I wouldn't be surprised to find that the vast bulk of your time is being spent performing parsing. There are some other calculations you're repeating over and over, such as `(24.443136 / size_h)` but I doubt those are as significant.

If you can work out some very crude measure for which areas will be covered for a particular city, you could avoid calculating the *exact* distance each time. For example, you could work out the minimum and maximum values for latitude and longitude which *might* be within 150 miles, and do a very quick test for each city before doing any more complicated maths.

Some stylistic issues:

- Use a foreach loop where you can
- Follow .NET naming conventions, e.g. `GetPixelColor` instead of `getPixelColor`
- Think about your names - the parameters for `getPixelColor` aren't really a width and height, are they? They're a *position* (e.g. x and y)
- I would generally encourage you to use braces for *every* loop and *every* `if` block. Not everyone goes along with that, but I find this sort of construct to be error-prone and hard to read:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < pixel_h; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < pixel_w; j++)
      {
          pixelColor = getPixelColor(i, j);
          bmp.SetPixel(j, i, pixelColor);

      }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

First: Create a class to store the data, and store it directly as doubles. Get rid of the string parsing over and over inside of GetPixel. That by itself will give you a large speedup.

Second: If you're still having performance problems, try this: Split the lat/lon into a grid, 150 miles by 150 miles. In GetPixel, only check the cities in that grid square, and the 8 surrounding grid squares. This way, you're checking the lat/lon of each city once, to put it in the right grid square, and then only checking a subset of them for each pixel.

Answer (score 1):

So your placedatalist has 66000 items. You should geographically sort the data before processing. You can very easily create a 2D array, let's say of 100x100 items. Then put each single record from placedatalist to this array to its geographical position. Then when you go with your computation, your 150-mile distance is for sure in the same slot in the geographical array or in one of the very next ones - horizontally and/or vertically, so you test 9 geographical "cells" of 10 thousand, which will bring you a massive speed up of computation. (Provided that overall maximum distance is no less than 15000 miles.)

Also, as mentioned above, you should definitely convert your data from string to numbers befer the start of computation. That also can help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's some very good answers and advice here, but even once you've implemented their advice - the Parallel Extensions may be of some use in breaking down the calculation of the colour:

you should be able to drop this in as a replacement for setting glow, and the for loop inside getPixelColour:

```
glow = placeDataList.AsParallel().Select(city =>
                                            {
                                                var cityPop = Convert.ToDouble(city[2]);
                                                var cityLat = Convert.ToDouble(city[3]);
                                                var cityLon = Convert.ToDouble(city[4]);
                                                var d = distance(testLat,
                                                                testLon,
                                                                cityLat,
                                                                cityLon,
                                                                "M");
                                                double glowComponent = 0.0;
                                                if (d < 150)
                                                {
                                                    glowComponent = (0.01*cityPop*Math.Pow(d, -2.5));
                                                }
                                                return glowComponent;
                                            }).Sum();
```